# Is there a way to get Chrome History and Bookmarks without using its local database in Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a Python program that is able to retrieve the Chrome history and the bookmarks of a user; however, when using the locally stored database in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History` I had the issue that if Chrome is currently opened I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/*******/chromer_history_reader.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute(select_statement)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Is there a way around this?

I have tried looking into ways to use the Chrome API for getting the history (https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/history) but it seems that I am only able to use the API using JavaScript and a Chrome Extension.

```py
import os
import sqlite3
from pprint import pprint

history_db = os.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\..\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History"

c = sqlite3.connect(history_db)
cursor = c.cursor()
select_statement = "SELECT urls.url, urls.visit_count FROM urls, visits WHERE urls.id = visits.url;"
cursor.execute(select_statement)

results = cursor.fetchall()

pprint(results)
```

What I would like is to be able to see the chrome history/bookmarks of a user even if chrome is currently open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the original History file on the computer with the program by copying your History file to another location on your computer that is not in the Chrome save folders by using the code below

```
import shutil

shutil.copy2(os.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\..\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\History", "NEW FILE LOCATION\\HISTORY")

history_db = "NEW FILE LOCATION\\HISTORY"
```